# Svelte-kit plugins

Tags: plugins, sveltekit

I am using svelte-kit 1.15.0 and trying to create a plugin.
I really googled it and even asked chatGPT.
This is the object my plugin defines :

```js
    {
        name: 'name',
        setup(stuff) {
            debugger;
        },
        config() {
            debugger;
        },
        configureServer(server) {
            debugger;
        },
        configResolved(config) {
            debugger;
        },
        buildEnd() {
            debugger;
        }
    }
```

I can add that plugin in `svelte.config.js`, none of the functions is called.
Is there one documentation that describes correctly the interface to use? (I found 1000s who describe it incorrectly)

Comment: Svelte has pre-processors, Vite has plugins, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: For something to be called - so that I can browse directories and make a list of files - but this doesn' t matter : For something to be called. What property is used?